# tns run android produces error: A problem occurred configuring root project 'core'. >compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: android, sdk, nativescript-angular

`I've installed Nativescript, and tns doctor returned no errors.
Then I installed android studio, and after that tns run returns the following error : "A problem occurred configuring root project 'core'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle"

build.gradle`

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

import javax.inject.Inject
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util.jar.JarEntry
import java.util.jar.JarFile

import static org.gradle.internal.logging.text.StyledTextOutput.Style

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: "gradle-helpers/BuildToolTask.gradle"
apply from: "gradle-helpers/CustomExecutionLogger.gradle"
apply from: "gradle-helpers/AnalyticsCollector.gradle"

def enableKotlin = (project.hasProperty("useKotlin") && project.useKotlin == "true")

if (enableKotlin) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

def onlyX86 = project.hasProperty("onlyX86")
if (onlyX86) {
    outLogger.withStyle(Style.Info).println "OnlyX86 build triggered."
}

//common
def BUILD_TOOLS_PATH = "$rootDir/build-tools"
def PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH = System.getenv("TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH")
def TYPINGS_PATH = "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/typings"
if (PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH != null) {
    TYPINGS_PATH = PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH
}

def PACKAGE_JSON = "package.json"

//static binding generator
def SBG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES = "sbg-java-dependencies.txt"
def SBG_INPUT_FILE = "sbg-input-file.txt"
def SBG_OUTPUT_FILE = "sbg-output-file.txt"
def SBG_JS_PARSED_FILES = "sbg-js-parsed-files.txt"
def SBG_BINDINGS_NAME = "sbg-bindings.txt"
def SBG_INTERFACE_NAMES = "sbg-interface-names.txt"
def INPUT_JS_DIR = "$projectDir/src/main/assets/app"
def OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR = "$projectDir/src/main/java"

//metadata generator
def MDG_OUTPUT_DIR = "mdg-output-dir.txt"
def MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES = "mdg-java-dependencies.txt"
def METADATA_OUT_PATH = "$projectDir/src/main/assets/metadata"

// paths to jar libraries
def pluginsJarLibraries = new LinkedList<String>()
def allJarLibraries = new LinkedList<String>()

def computeKotlinVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("kotlinVersion") ? kotlinVersion : "${ns_default_kotlin_version}" }
def computeCompileSdkVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("compileSdk") ? compileSdk : NS_DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int }
def computeTargetSdkVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("targetSdk") ? targetSdk : NS_DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int }
def computeBuildToolsVersion = { ->
    project.hasProperty("buildToolsVersion") ? buildToolsVersion : NS_DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION as String
}

def enableAnalytics = (project.hasProperty("gatherAnalyticsData") && project.gatherAnalyticsData == "true")
def enableVerboseMDG = project.gradle.startParameter.logLevel.name() == 'DEBUG'
def analyticsFilePath = "$rootDir/analytics/build-statistics.json"
def analyticsCollector = project.ext.AnalyticsCollector.withOutputPath(analyticsFilePath)
if (enableAnalytics) {
    analyticsCollector.markUseKotlinPropertyInApp(enableKotlin)
    analyticsCollector.writeAnalyticsFile()
}

project.ext.selectedBuildType = project.hasProperty("release") ? "release" : "debug"

buildscript {
    def applyBuildScriptConfigurations = { ->
        def absolutePathToAppResources = getAppResourcesPath()
        def pathToBuildScriptGradle = "$absolutePathToAppResources/Android/buildscript.gradle"
        def buildScriptGradle = file(pathToBuildScriptGradle)
        if (buildScriptGradle.exists()) {
            outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + applying user-defined buildscript from ${buildScriptGradle}"
            apply from: pathToBuildScriptGradle, to: buildscript
        }

        nativescriptDependencies.each { dep ->
            def pathToPluginBuildScriptGradle = "$rootDir/${dep.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID/buildscript.gradle"
            def pluginBuildScriptGradle = file(pathToPluginBuildScriptGradle)
            if (pluginBuildScriptGradle.exists()) {
                outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + applying user-defined buildscript from dependency ${pluginBuildScriptGradle}"
                apply from: pathToPluginBuildScriptGradle, to: buildscript
            }
        }
    }
    applyBuildScriptConfigurations()
}
///////////// CONFIGURATIONS ////////////////

def applyBeforePluginGradleConfiguration = { ->
    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def pathToBeforePluginGradle = "$appResourcesPath/Android/before-plugins.gradle"
    def beforePluginGradle = file(pathToBeforePluginGradle)
    if (beforePluginGradle.exists()) {
        outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + applying user-defined configuration from ${beforePluginGradle}"
        apply from: pathToBeforePluginGradle
    }
}

def applyAppGradleConfiguration = { ->
    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def pathToAppGradle = "$appResourcesPath/Android/app.gradle"
    def appGradle = file(pathToAppGradle)
    if (appGradle.exists()) {
        outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + applying user-defined configuration from ${appGradle}"
        apply from: pathToAppGradle
    } else {
        outLogger.withStyle(Style.Info).println "\t + couldn't load user-defined configuration from ${appGradle}. File doesn't exist."
    }
}

def applyPluginGradleConfigurations = { ->
    nativescriptDependencies.each { dep ->
        def includeGradlePath = "$rootDir/${dep.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID/include.gradle"
        if (file(includeGradlePath).exists()) {
            apply from: includeGradlePath
        }
    }
}

def getAppIdentifier = { packageJsonMap ->
    def appIdentifier = ""
    if (packageJsonMap && packageJsonMap.nativescript) {
        appIdentifier = packageJsonMap.nativescript.id
        if (!(appIdentifier instanceof String)) {
            appIdentifier = appIdentifier.android
        }
    }

    return appIdentifier
}

def setAppIdentifier = { ->
    outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + setting applicationId"
    File packageJsonFile = new File("$USER_PROJECT_ROOT/$PACKAGE_JSON")

    if (packageJsonFile.exists()) {
        def content = packageJsonFile.getText("UTF-8")
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def packageJsonMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(content)
        def appIdentifier = getAppIdentifier(packageJsonMap)

        if (appIdentifier) {
            project.ext.nsApplicationIdentifier = appIdentifier
            android.defaultConfig.applicationId = appIdentifier
        }
    }
}

android {
    applyBeforePluginGradleConfiguration()

    if (enableKotlin) {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion computeCompileSdkVersion()
    buildToolsVersion computeBuildToolsVersion()

    defaultConfig {
        def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile))
        def minSdkVer = manifest."uses-sdk"."@android:minSdkVersion".text() ?: NS_DEFAULT_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        minSdkVersion minSdkVer
        targetSdkVersion computeTargetSdkVersion()
        ndk {
            if (onlyX86) {
                abiFilters 'x86'
            } else {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8//////
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ["$projectDir/libs/jni", "$projectDir/snapshot-build/build/ndk-build/libs"]
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty("release")) {
                if (project.hasProperty("ksPath") &&
                        project.hasProperty("ksPassword") &&
                        project.hasProperty("alias") &&
                        project.hasProperty("password")) {

                    storeFile file(ksPath)
                    storePassword ksPassword
                    keyAlias alias
                    keyPassword password
                }
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

  

////////// CONFIGURATION PHASE /////////////////

task addDependenciesFromNativeScriptPlugins {
    nativescriptDependencies.each { dep ->
        def aarFiles = fileTree(dir: file("$rootDir/${dep.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID"), include: ["**/*.aar"])
        aarFiles.each { aarFile ->
            def length = aarFile.name.length() - 4
            def fileName = aarFile.name[0..<length]
            outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + adding aar plugin dependency: " + aarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            project.dependencies.add("implementation", [name: fileName, ext: "aar"])
        }

        def jarFiles = fileTree(dir: file("$rootDir/${dep.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID"), include: ["**/*.jar"])
        jarFiles.each { jarFile ->
            def jarFileAbsolutePath = jarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + adding jar plugin dependency: $jarFileAbsolutePath"
            pluginsJarLibraries.add(jarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        project.dependencies.add("implementation", jarFiles)
    }
}

task addDependenciesFromAppResourcesLibraries {
    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def appResourcesLibraries = file("$appResourcesPath/Android/libs")
    if (appResourcesLibraries.exists()) {
        def aarFiles = fileTree(dir: appResourcesLibraries, include: ["**/*.aar"])
        aarFiles.each { aarFile ->
            def length = aarFile.name.length() - 4
            def fileName = aarFile.name[0..<length]
            outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + adding aar library dependency: " + aarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            project.dependencies.add("implementation", [name: fileName, ext: "aar"])
        }

        def jarFiles = fileTree(dir: appResourcesLibraries, include: ["**/*.jar"])
        jarFiles.each { jarFile ->
            def jarFileAbsolutePath = jarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "\t + adding jar plugin dependency: $jarFileAbsolutePath"
            pluginsJarLibraries.add(jarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        project.dependencies.add("implementation", jarFiles)
    }
}

if (failOnCompilationWarningsEnabled()) {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:all' << "-Werror"
        options.deprecation = true
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded({ DefaultTask currentTask ->
    if (currentTask =~ /generate.+BuildConfig/) {
        currentTask.finalizedBy(extractAllJars)
        extractAllJars.finalizedBy(collectAllJars)
    }
    if (currentTask =~ /compile.+JavaWithJavac/) {
        currentTask.dependsOn(runSbg)
        currentTask.finalizedBy(buildMetadata)
    }
    if (currentTask =~ /merge.*Assets/) {
        currentTask.dependsOn(buildMetadata)
    }
    // ensure buildMetadata is done before R8 to allow custom proguard from metadata
    if (currentTask =~ /minify.*WithR8/) {
        currentTask.dependsOn(buildMetadata)
    }
    if (currentTask =~ /assemble.*Debug/ || currentTask =~ /assemble.*Release/) {
        currentTask.finalizedBy("validateAppIdMatch")
    }
})

////////////// EXECUTUION PHASE //////////

task runSbg(type: BuildToolTask) {
    dependsOn "collectAllJars"
    if (!findProject(':static-binding-generator').is(null)) {
        dependsOn ':static-binding-generator:jar'
    }

    outputs.dir("$OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR/com/tns/gen")
    inputs.dir(INPUT_JS_DIR)
    inputs.dir(extractedDependenciesDir)

    workingDir "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"
    main "-jar"

    def paramz = new ArrayList<String>()
    paramz.add("static-binding-generator.jar")

    if (failOnCompilationWarningsEnabled()) {
        paramz.add("-show-deprecation-warnings")
    }

    setOutputs outLogger

    args paramz

    doFirst {
        new File("$OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR/com/tns/gen").deleteDir()
    }
}

def failOnCompilationWarningsEnabled() {
    return project.hasProperty("failOnCompilationWarnings") && (failOnCompilationWarnings || failOnCompilationWarnings.toBoolean())
}

def explodeAar(File compileDependency, File outputDir) {
    logger.info("explodeAar: Extracting ${compileDependency.path} -> ${outputDir.path}")

    if (compileDependency.name.endsWith(".aar")) {
        JarFile jar = new JarFile(compileDependency)
        Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries()
        while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry file = (JarEntry) enumEntries.nextElement()
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                continue
            }
            if (file.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
                def targetFile = new File(outputDir, file.name)
                InputStream inputStream = jar.getInputStream(file)
                new File(targetFile.parent).mkdirs()
                Files.copy(inputStream, targetFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
            }
        }
        jar.close()
    } else if (compileDependency.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
        copy {
            from compileDependency.absolutePath
            into outputDir
        }
    }
}

def md5(String string) {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    digest.update(string.bytes)
    return new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16).padLeft(32, '0')
}

class WorkerTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Inject
    WorkerExecutor getWorkerExecutor() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}

class EmptyRunnable implements Runnable {
    void run() {
    }
}

def getMergedAssetsOutputPath() {
    if (!project.hasProperty("mergedAssetsOutputPath")) {
        // mergedAssetsOutputPath not found fallback to the default value for android gradle plugin 3.5.1
        project.ext.mergedAssetsOutputPath = "$projectDir/build/intermediates/merged_assets/" + project.selectedBuildType + "/out"
    }
    return project.ext.mergedAssetsOutputPath
}

// Discover all jars and dynamically create tasks for the extraction of each of them
project.ext.allJars = []
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        def buildType = project.selectedBuildType
        def jars = []
        def artifactType = Attribute.of('artifactType', String)
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.buildType.name == buildType) {
                variant.getCompileClasspath().each { fileDependency ->
                    processJar(fileDependency, jars)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def processJar(File jar, jars) {
    if (!jars.contains(jar)) {
        jars.add(jar)
        def destDir = md5(jar.path)
        def outputDir = new File(Paths.get(extractedDependenciesDir, destDir).normalize().toString())

        def taskName = "extract_${jar.name}_to_${destDir}"
        logger.debug("Creating dynamic task ${taskName}")

        // Add discovered jars as dependencies of cleanupAllJars.
        // This is cruicial for cloud builds because they are different
        // on each incremental build (as each time the gradle user home
        // directory is a randomly generated string)
        cleanupAllJars.inputs.files jar

        task "${taskName}"(type: WorkerTask) {
            dependsOn cleanupAllJars
            extractAllJars.dependsOn it

            // This dependency seems redundant but probably due to some Gradle issue with workers,
            // without it `runSbg` sporadically starts before all extraction tasks have finished and
            // fails due to missing JARs
            runSbg.dependsOn it

            inputs.files jar
            outputs.dir outputDir

            doLast {
                // Runing in parallel no longer seems to bring any benefit.
                // It mattered only when we were extracting JARs from AARs.
                // To try it simply remove the following comments.
                // workerExecutor.submit(EmptyRunnable.class) {
                explodeAar(jar, outputDir)
                // }
            }
        }
        project.ext.allJars.add([file: jar, outputDir: outputDir])
    }
}

task cleanupAllJars {
    // We depend on the list of libs directories that might contain aar or jar files
    // and on the list of all discovered jars
    inputs.files(pluginDependencies)

    outputs.files cleanupAllJarsTimestamp

    doLast {
        def allDests = project.ext.allJars*.outputDir*.name
        def dir = new File(extractedDependenciesDir)
        if (dir.exists()) {
            dir.eachDir {
                // An old directory which is no longer a dependency (e.g. orphaned by a deleted plugin)
                if (!allDests.contains(it.name)) {
                    logger.info("Task cleanupAllJars: Deleting orphaned ${it.path}")
                    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(it)
                }
            }
        }
        new File(cleanupAllJarsTimestamp).write ""
    }
}


// Placeholder task which depends on all dynamically generated extraction tasks
task extractAllJars {
    dependsOn cleanupAllJars
    outputs.files extractAllJarsTimestamp

    doLast {
        new File(cleanupAllJarsTimestamp).write ""
    }
}

task collectAllJars {
    dependsOn extractAllJars
    description "gathers all paths to jar dependencies before building metadata with them"

    def sdkPath = android.sdkDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
    def androidJar = sdkPath + "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"

    doFirst {
        def allJarPaths = new LinkedList<String>()
        allJarPaths.add(androidJar)
        allJarPaths.addAll(pluginsJarLibraries)
        def ft = fileTree(dir: extractedDependenciesDir, include: "**/*.jar")
        ft.each { currentJarFile ->
            allJarPaths.add(currentJarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES").withWriter { out ->
            allJarPaths.each { out.println it }
        }
        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES").withWriter { out ->
            allJarPaths.each {
                if (it.endsWith(".jar")) {
                    out.println it
                }
            }
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_INPUT_FILE").withWriter { out ->
            out.println INPUT_JS_DIR
        }
        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_OUTPUT_FILE").withWriter { out ->
            out.println OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR
        }

        allJarLibraries.addAll(allJarPaths)
    }
}

task copyMetadataFilters(type: Copy) {
    from "$rootDir/whitelist.mdg", "$rootDir/blacklist.mdg"
    into "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"
}

task copyMetadata {
    doLast {
        copy {
          from "$projectDir/src/main/assets/metadata"
          into getMergedAssetsOutputPath() + "/metadata"
        }
    }
}

task buildMetadata(type: BuildToolTask) {
    if (!findProject(':android-metadata-generator').is(null)) {
        dependsOn ':android-metadata-generator:jar'
    }

    dependsOn copyMetadataFilters

    // As some external gradle plugins can reorder the execution order of the tasks it may happen that buildMetadata is executed after merge{Debug/Release}Assets
    // in that case the metadata won't be included in the result apk and it will crash, so to avoid this we are adding the copyMetadata task which will manually copy
    // the metadata files in the merge assets folder and they will be added to the result apk

    // The next line is added to avoid adding another copyData implementation from the firebase plugin - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/3943bb9147f43c41599e801d026378eba93d3f3a/publish/scripts/installer.js#L1105
    //buildMetadata.finalizedBy(copyMetadata)
    finalizedBy copyMetadata

    description "builds metadata with provided jar dependencies"

    inputs.files("$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES")

    // make MDG aware of whitelist.mdg and blacklist.mdg files
    inputs.files(project.fileTree(dir: "$rootDir", include: "**/*.mdg"))

    def classesDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/javac"
    inputs.dir(classesDir)

    def kotlinClassesDir = "$buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes"
    if (file(kotlinClassesDir).exists()) {
        inputs.dir(kotlinClassesDir)
    }

    outputs.files("$METADATA_OUT_PATH/treeNodeStream.dat", "$METADATA_OUT_PATH/treeStringsStream.dat", "$METADATA_OUT_PATH/treeValueStream.dat")

    workingDir "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"
    main "-jar"

    doFirst {
        // get compiled classes to pass to metadata generator
        // these need to be called after the classes have compiled
        assert file(classesDir).exists()

        new File(getMergedAssetsOutputPath() + "/metadata").deleteDir()

        def classesSubDirs = new File(classesDir).listFiles()
        def selectedBuildType = project.ext.selectedBuildType

        def generatedClasses = new LinkedList<String>()
        for (File subDir : classesSubDirs) {
            if (subDir.getName() == selectedBuildType) {
                generatedClasses.add(subDir.getAbsolutePath())
            }
        }

        if (file(kotlinClassesDir).exists()) {
            def kotlinClassesSubDirs = new File(kotlinClassesDir).listFiles()
            for (File subDir : kotlinClassesSubDirs) {
                if (subDir.getName() == selectedBuildType) {
                    generatedClasses.add(subDir.getAbsolutePath())
                }
            }
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_OUTPUT_DIR").withWriter { out ->
            out.println "$METADATA_OUT_PATH"
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES").withWriterAppend { out ->
            generatedClasses.each { out.println it }
        }

        setOutputs outLogger

        def paramz = new ArrayList<String>()
        paramz.add("android-metadata-generator.jar")

        if(enableAnalytics){
            paramz.add("analyticsFilePath=$analyticsFilePath")
        }

        if(enableVerboseMDG){
            paramz.add("verbose")
        }

        args paramz.toArray()
    }
}

task generateTypescriptDefinitions(type: BuildToolTask) {
    if (!findProject(':dts-generator').is(null)) {
        dependsOn ':dts-generator:jar'
    }

    def paramz = new ArrayList<String>()
    def includeDirs = ["com.android.support", "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion]

    workingDir "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"
    main "-jar"

    doFirst {
        delete "$TYPINGS_PATH"

        paramz.add("dts-generator.jar")
        paramz.add("-input")

        for (String jarPath : allJarLibraries) {
            // don't generate typings for runtime jars and classes
            if (shouldIncludeDirForTypings(jarPath, includeDirs)) {
                paramz.add(jarPath)
            }
        }

        paramz.add("-output")
        paramz.add("$TYPINGS_PATH")

        new File("$TYPINGS_PATH").mkdirs()

        logger.info("Task generateTypescriptDefinitions: Call dts-generator.jar with arguments: " + paramz.toString().replaceAll(',', ''))
        outLogger.withStyle(Style.SuccessHeader).println "Task generateTypescriptDefinitions: Call dts-generator.jar with arguments: " + paramz.toString().replaceAll(',', '')

        setOutputs outLogger

        args paramz.toArray()
    }
}

generateTypescriptDefinitions.onlyIf {
    (project.hasProperty("generateTypings") && Boolean.parseBoolean(project.generateTypings)) || PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH != null
}

collectAllJars.finalizedBy(generateTypescriptDefinitions)

static def shouldIncludeDirForTypings(path, includeDirs) {
    for (String p : includeDirs) {
        if (path.indexOf(p) > -1) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

task copyTypings {
    doLast {
        outLogger.withStyle(Style.Info).println "Copied generated typings to application root level. Make sure to import android.d.ts in reference.d.ts"

        copy {
            from "$TYPINGS_PATH"
            into "$USER_PROJECT_ROOT"
        }
    }
}

copyTypings.onlyIf { generateTypescriptDefinitions.didWork }
generateTypescriptDefinitions.finalizedBy(copyTypings)

task validateAppIdMatch {
    doLast {
        def lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator")

        if (project.hasProperty("nsApplicationIdentifier") && !project.hasProperty("release")) {
            if (project.nsApplicationIdentifier != android.defaultConfig.applicationId) {
                def errorMessage = "${lineSeparator}WARNING: The Application identifier is different from the one inside \"package.json\" file.$lineSeparator" +
                        "NativeScript CLI might not work properly.$lineSeparator" +
                        "Remove applicationId from app.gradle and update the \"nativescript.id\" in package.json.$lineSeparator" +
                        "Actual: ${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}$lineSeparator" +
                        "Expected(from \"package.json\"): ${project.nsApplicationIdentifier}$lineSeparator"

                logger.error(errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}

//////////////// OPTIONAL TASKS //////////

//////// custom clean ///////////
task cleanSbg(type: Delete) {
    delete "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_JS_PARSED_FILES",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_INTERFACE_NAMES",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_BINDINGS_NAME",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_INPUT_FILE",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_OUTPUT_FILE",
            "$OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR/com/tns/gen"
}

task cleanMdg(type: Delete) {
    delete "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_OUTPUT_DIR",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/whitelist.mdg",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/blacklist.mdg",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES",
            "$METADATA_OUT_PATH"
}
cleanSbg.dependsOn(cleanMdg)
clean.dependsOn(cleanSbg)
```

I tried playing around with the sdk properties.

Answer (score 1):

NativeScript usually adds this information by itself depending on what sdk versions you have installed. You might want to update the cli:

```
npm i -g nativescript
```

or manually set in your `app.gradle` inside the `App_Resources` folder:

```
android {
...
  compileSdkVersion 32 // change 32 to whatever sdk you want or have installed
```

Comment: upgrading nativescript helped me resolve Gradle issue I was dealing from 3 days